# How can I query the path to an NLog log file?

Tags: .net, nlog

I've configured a file target for NLog as follows:

```
<targets>
  <target name="asyncFile" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
    <target xsi:type="File" name="logfile" fileName="${basedir}/Logs/${shortdate}.log"
          layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
  </target>    
</targets>
```

How can I query the actual filesystem path (`fileName`) of this `File` target via NLog's API?

Comment: What is your requirement? Why do you need to know the path?

Comment: @ckeller It's interesting because I don't necessarily know what `${basedir}` evaluates to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just tried to get this information via the [configuration api](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-API).

[image]

Sadly it looks like the configuration is evaluated by the actual target and is not resolved in the configuration.

As [`{basedir}`](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Basedir-Layout-Renderer) refers to the appdomain base directory you could simply read this value on your own.

```
var basedirPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
    private string GetLogFile()
    {
        var fileTarget = LogManager.Configuration.AllTargets.FirstOrDefault(t => t is FileTarget) as FileTarget;
        return fileTarget == null ? string.Empty : fileTarget.FileName.Render(new LogEventInfo { Level = LogLevel.Info });
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You could use nLog's api inside of code instead of an xml configuration file.  Then, in your application, you assign the log's file path to a variable, and use that variable as the target's filename.  You can access that variable, OR change it anytime you like (my snippet, here, is defined inside of a class).

```
Private MainNlogConfig As New LoggingConfiguration()
Dim localrule As New LoggingRule(*, LogLevel.Info, locallogtarget)
MainNlogConfig..AddTarget("file", locallogtarget)

With locallogtarget
    .Layout = "${longdate} ${logger} ${message}"
    .FileName = appdir & appName & ".log"  '----->LOOK HERE!
End With
LogManager.Configuration = MainNlogConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup the FileTarget and resolve the filename like this:

```cs
var fileTarget = LogManager.Configuration?.FindTargetByName<NLog.Targets.FileTarget>("logfile");
string filePath = fileTarget?.FileName.Render(LogEventInfo.CreateNullEvent());
string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
```